# Numerical model of 1D equations for compressible flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, stability

The equations for 1D compressible flow are

$$\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial t}-A\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial x}=0,$$
$$\frac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial t}-B\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}=0,$$
with $u(x,t)$ the velocity, $v(x,t)$ the specific volume and $A,B$ constant. A simple explicit finite difference formulation of this problem could be

\begin{align}
  u^{n+1}_i &= A\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(v^n_i-v^n_{i-1})+u^n_i,\\
  v^{n+1}_i &= B\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(u^n_i-u^n_{i-1})+v^n_i
\end{align}

where all new values are denoted with $^{n+1}$, values from previous timestep are denoted with $^n$ and $i=1...N$ for $N$ points in the spatial domain. At the inlet, we can impose boundary conditions

$$u_0=u_\text{in}$$
$$v_0=v_\text{in}$$

When running this model, the solutions start to oscillate at the inlet. These oscillations grow in amplitude and advect through the domain. So what causes these errors? Since it start at the inlet it is probably related to the boundary condition. Decreasing the timestep size does not help.

Comment: It's fairly common with a first-order finite difference approximation. Have you tried a different stencil (e.g., $v_{i+1}-v_{i}$ or $(v_{i+1}-v_{i-1})/2$ or using [higher order stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient))? Or using a different scheme altogether (e.g., backward Euler, Crank Nicolson, etc)?

Comment: Also, it's fairly common to use $n$ for the temporal index, e.g. $v(x,t)\to v_i^n$, and a further time step would be denoted as $v_i^{n+1}$.

Comment: I will definitely try other schemes. Although in my experience first order upwind always works for right-travelling waves.

Comment: I implemented a central scheme and the inlet behaves properly, but now the outlet gives strange results. Even when I discretize the last node with first order upwind, the results are not good.

Comment: *...discretize the last node with first order upwind...* are you not using ghost cells? Akin to lpz's answer, have you performed a Fourier stability analysis (i.e., assume a solution of the form $u_j^n\equiv \alpha^n\exp(ijt)$ which requires $|\alpha^{n+1}/\alpha^n|\leq1$) to determine if the system is stable for any FD scheme?

Comment: You might also want to try a [Lax update](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method) scheme (which uses $(u_{i+1}^0+u_{i-1}^0)/2$ for the last term of your updates) to see if that quashes some of the errors.

Comment: I made up some numbers for my own testing, but I get oscillations to appear with an inlet condition & free boundary at the right end. These oscillations disappear using the Lax update I linked below. Probably the issue is due to the scheme being unconditionally unstable & using alternative means makes it at least conditionally stable.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you can work out everything analytically. In the bulk, this is formally equivalent to the lossless [telegrapher’s equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher%27s_equations), depending on your background, this analogy can help build intuition. In particular, it is not surprising that you get progressive waves forming. Also, it gives you another natural discretization scheme:
$$
\begin{align}
u^{n+1}_i &=A\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(v^n_i-v^n_{i-1})+u^n_i\\
v^{n+1}_i &=B\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(u^n_{i+1}-u^n_i)+v^n_i
\end{align}
$$

From this analogy, you can already something strange with your boundary conditions. You would rather expect to specify a condition at the inlet and another at the outlet, not both at the inlet.

You can solve the original continuous problem by mode expansion. I’ll assume up to a change of units of $u,v,x,t$ that $A=B=1$ and $x\in[0,1]$. The normalized equations:
$$
\partial_tu-\partial_xv=0 \\
\partial_tv-\partial_xu=0
$$

Up to a Fourier decomposition of the time varying $u_{in},v_{in}$, you can assume with no loss of generality that:
$$
u_{in}=Ue^{i\omega t}\\
v_{in}=Ve^{i\omega t}
$$
You can get a solution by separation of variables. To match the temporal initial condition, you’ll need to add homogenous solutions satisfying $u_0=v_0=0$. The separated variable solution:
$$
u=\left(U\cos(\omega x)+iV\sin(\omega x)\right)e^{i\omega t}\\
v=\left(iU\sin(\omega x)+V\cos(\omega x)\right)e^{i\omega t}
$$

However, the problem arises when you investigate the homogenous solutions. By imposing two conditions at $x=0$, the problem is overdetermined and there are none. Your problem is therefore ill posed. Either you put for initial values precisely the previous solution, in which case it will evolve nicely, or else the equations “breaks down” and there are no solutions.

This explains why your simulations are unstable. When you discretize, you apparently recover a system where you can feed in any initial conditions, but there is no reason for it to behave like the particular solution in the continuum case.

I would recommend looking into the physics and check whether the boundary conditions are the correct ones.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer, it gives a bit of insight. As to why I use these boundary conditions: prescribing an inlet velocity seems rather logical speaking from a physical point of view. For the specific volume I was not sure. I guess an alternative would be to extrapolate from the interior.

Comment: Yes check whether the condition on the volume is not on the outlet for example. If you give more context for the problem, I could perhaps help you find the correct bc’s. In any case, as long as the original problem is ill posed, there is no point looking for a numerical scheme. I did not understand your last sentence though.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\ee}{\operatorname{e\!}{}}$
$\newcommand{\iu}{\mathrm{i}\mkern1mu}$
We can write the PDEs as a single matrix equation,
$$\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}-\mathsf{A}\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}=0$$
where,
$$q=\left(\begin{array}{c}u \\ v\end{array}\right),\quad\mathsf{A}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}0 & A \\ B & 0\end{array}\right).$$
This discretizes using OP's form as,
$$ q_i^{n+1}=q_i^n+\mathsf{A}\frac{dt}{dx}\left(q_i^n-q_{i-1}^n\right).\tag{1}$$
From this we can do the [von Neumann stability analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_stability_analysis) (or Fourier stability) by letting $q_i^n=\hat{q}\gamma^n\ee^{\iu i\theta}$. After some cancelations, we end up finding that
$$\gamma=1+\mathsf{A}\frac{dt}{dx}\left(1-\ee^{-\iu\theta}\right)$$
which, unless $A,\,B$ are negative, this scheme is *unconditionally unstable* (which would requires $\vert\gamma\vert\leq1$), hence, the observed oscillations are effectively expected.

---

To damp these oscillations, a different scheme must be used. One such example that I tested was to use the [Lax-Friedrichs method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax%E2%80%93Friedrichs_method) which would recast Eq (1) as
$$ q_i^{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(q_{i+1}^n+q_{i-1}^n\right)+\mathsf{A}\frac{dt}{dx}\left(q_i^n-q_{i-1}^n\right).\tag{2}$$
which is conditionally stable (requires $\vert\mathsf{A}\times dt/dx\vert\leq1$).